# How to test accordion using Protractor?

Tags: angularjs, protractor, jasmine-node

Sometimes my user reports that accordion in my application is not working . So i want test whether the accordion is working or not working. I am using Angular js in frontend. Currently i am testing using protractor e2e framework.

My accordion markup looks like

before clicking the accordion division

```
<div id="accordion"></div>
```

after click

```
<div id="accordion-expand">
```

so the change is id

I find difficult while identifying css change in protractor. is there any other way to test this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
// Given
var accordion = element(by.id('accordion'));
expect(accordion.isPresent()).toBeTruthy();

// When
accordion.click();

// Then
expect(accordion.isPresent()).toBeFalsy();
expect(element(by.id('accordion-expand')).isPresent()).toBeTruthy();
```

Hope this helps.